# Overriding node.js console.log to file in custom logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I've to manage `node.js` application with is unfortunately no longer supported by producer. Since I've never been deep into `node.js` before (just some front end js) I've a doubt how to change logging from console into file. Here is actual code responsible for logging:

```
if (config.logToStdOut){
log = function(func){
    return function(what){
        func(what)
        what.ts = new Date()
        console.log(what)
    }
}(log)}
```

i've tried to do it using `fs` and `writestream` and adding simple `logFile.Write(what)`, but since `what` is a kind of object using such simple method produces in log only `Object object` entry, nothing more. So any ideas how to make this console logging into file?

Thanks in advance!

Ok, I dig up that `what` is actually JSON object. However new question arised. When I try to redirect output to file following method works:

```
console.log = function(what) {  
logFile.write(JSON.stringify(what, null, 2))}
```

however when I try utilize original method (which also adds timestamp to JSON) it does not work, i.e.:

```
log = function(func){
    return function(what){
        func(what)
        what.ts = new Date()           
        logFileTest.write(JSON.stringify(what, null, 2))

}
}(log)
```

file is created, however it is empty.

Any ideas why? For my understanding when `console.log(JSON object)` is used it is exactly the same object as in `fs.write(JSON.stringify(JSON Object)`? Or no?

Comment: Maybe try to put in console.log method JSON.stringify(what)

Comment: Yep, it can be JSON object! Thx, I'll check it.